# How to take spherical derivatives of a spherical vector?

Tags: calculus

I am studying spherical coordinates, and I used some math software to calculate the following:

Given the vector field
$\overrightarrow f(r,\theta,\phi)=0\,\hat r\,+\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\,\hat\theta+0\,\hat\phi$

Take the negative derivative of $\overrightarrow f(r,\theta,\phi)$ with respect to theta:

$$ -\frac{\partial\overrightarrow f}{\partial\theta}=\left(-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\cos(\phi)^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\,+\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\cos(\phi)^2\sin(\theta)^2\,-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)^2\sin(\theta)\,+g(r,\theta,\phi)\sin(\theta)^2\sin(\phi)^2\,+\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,+\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\cos(\theta)^2\right)\hat r\,+\left(-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\cos(\phi)^2\cos(\theta)^2\,+\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\cos(\phi)^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,-\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\cos(\theta)^2\sin(\phi)^2\,+\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)^2\cos(\theta)\,-\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}g(r,\theta,\phi)\right)\sin(\theta)^2\,-\,g(r,\theta,\phi)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\right)\hat\theta\,+\,0\,\hat\phi$$

Where do all these terms come from?  A similar derivative in Cartesian coordinates has much fewer terms.

I have also posted this question to Maple Primes.

https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/234851-How-To-Show-The-Solution-For-Spherical

Answer (score 1):

Taking differential, it is easy to see that
$d \vec{f}
= dg\ \vec{e}_\theta + g\ d \vec{e}_\theta
= \left[ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\ \vec{e}_\theta - g\  \vec{e}_r \right] d\theta
$ from which
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial \theta}
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\ \vec{e}_\theta - g\  \vec{e}_r
$$
If you simplify your expression, you should also find this result.